# Derive password string from random bytes

Tags: algorithm, random, passwords

I have 32 bytes. I need to derive from them a password string (which will hopefully work on most websites), given certain restrictions.

- All characters must be in one of { A-Z, a-z, 0-9, !@#$% }.
- The string will have at least two characters from each of the above sets.
- The string must be exactly 15 characters long.

Currently I'm using the bytes to seed a non-cryptographically-secure PRNG, which I'm then using to:

1. get two random characters from each of the sets and push them.
2. fill the rest of the string with randomly chosen characters from any of the sets.
3. shuffle the string.

Is this valid, and is there a simpler way?

Comment: Different passwords could be derived from the same 32 byte sequence, and different 32 byte sequences could lead to the same password... so why not just choose a random password? The relationship with the 32 bytes seems to be of no consequence.

Comment: It's one of those deterministic password managers where it derives all your passwords from a master password, using your email address and the website as salts.